# Retrieve data from DataGridView to TEXTBOXS

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from subdiseases where id_subdiss=" + dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    { 
        cn.Close(); 
    }
    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr4 = null;
    dr4 = cmd.ExecuteReader() ;
    while (dr4.Read())
    {
        a = dr4["id_diss"].ToString();
        comboBox1.Text = dr4["name_diss"].ToString();
        namesub.Text = dr4["name_subdiss"].ToString();
        namedet.Text = dr4["details"].ToString();
    }
    dr4.Close();
}
```

I get this error:

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

Comment: And what shows up in Google when you researched that error message?

Comment: double check that your error is occurring in the method that you posted. Use a debugged to step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned in a comment below your post, make sure that you're getting this error on the very method that you posted, as it looks fine to me. Normally you would get this error if you closed the reader inside your loop or if you tried reading it on a closed db connection. You might want to try to just open the connection once at the beginning and closing it once at the end, removing that open close validation you have, although that shouldn't be the issue.